# JSON, изменение значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, рекурсия, словари

Есть JSON (много вложенных словарей).
Есть массив ключей.
Есть значение.

Нужно изменить значение одного из элементов в JSON (искомый ключ можно найти следуя по массиву ключей).

JSON:

```
{"a" : {"b": 3}}
```

массив ключей:

```
["a", "b"]
```

значение:

```
"c"
```

Нужно число 3 заменить на строку `"c"`, чтобы получилось `{"a" : {"b": "c"}}`.

Вообще нужен метод

```
def func(some_json, keys_array, value):
    ...
    return new_json
```

Comment: что не получается?

Comment: @virvaldium не могу придумать метод

Answer (score 4):

Можно так (без рекурсии):

```
def func(some_json, keys_array, value):
    # Сделаем копию словаря
    new_json = dict(some_json)

    last_dict = new_json

    while True:
        key = keys_array.pop(0)
        if not keys_array:
            break

        # Проваливаемся в следующий внутренний словарь
        last_dict = last_dict.get(key)

    last_dict[key] = value

    return new_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {"a": {"b": 3}}
    new_data = func(data, ["a", "b"], 'c')
    print(new_data)  # {'a': {'b': 'c'}}

    data = {"a": {"b": {'c': {'d': {'e': {'f': 777}}}}}}
    new_data = func(data, ["a", "b", 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'FOOBAR')
    print(new_data)  # {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': {'f': 'FOOBAR'}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Также можно восользоваться ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013719

```
import copy
from functools import reduce
import json


json = {'a': {'b': 3}}
value = 'c'
keys_array = ['a', 'b']

new_json = copy.deepcopy(json)
reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys_array[:-1], new_json)[keys_array[-1]] = value

print(new_json)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в данном случае воспользовался модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), который позволяет адресоваться в словаре используя пути (как в OS):

```
In [1]: import dpath    # pip install dpath

In [2]: x = {
   ...:     "l0": {"l1": {"l2": {"l3": "deeply nested"}}}
   ...: }

In [3]: dpath.util.set(x, '/l0/l1/l2/l3', 'NEW_VALUE')
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: x
Out[4]: {'l0': {'l1': {'l2': {'l3': 'NEW_VALUE'}}}}
```

если путь задан в виде списка, то его можно преобразовать используя `'/'.join(lst)`:

```
In [5]: dpath.util.set(x, '/'.join(['l0','l1','l2','l3']), 'YET_NEWER_VALUE')
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: x
Out[6]: {'l0': {'l1': {'l2': {'l3': 'YET_NEWER_VALUE'}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант с рекурсией

```
def func(json, array, val):
    if not array:                                # если массив пустой
        return val
    json, array = dict(json), list(array)        # делаем копии
    key = array.pop(0)                           # вытаскиваем ключ
    json[key] = func(json[key], array, val)      # рекурсия
    return json
```